# how to prevent C program crash caused by external program

Tags: c

I have a C program calling an external command using `system`, however, I don't know why the external program will crash occasionally, which cause the whole program crashes, is there anyway that I can prevent my program crash even though the external program crashes?

EDIT1: 
here is some code, this is part of a big project, as can be seen in the code, originally they used scp to transfer file to/from server, due to some limitation, I wrote our own version of scp called scpcontract and scpexpand, then I substitute it to the function, then the whole program began to crash occasionally, and the output of the crash is report "KEYERROR" and no traceback (and I can't print them, I don't know why), but when I look at kernel ring message, I saw there is one program crash called "expand.so" at the same time, I am not sure what is this "expand.so", as I don't have this file in the project.

```
struct context {
    const char *path;
    const char *user_buf;
    int user_buf_size;
};


#define execute(fmt, ...) ({ \
    char buf[8196]; \
    snprintf(buf, 8173, fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__); \
    strcat(buf, ">/dev/null 2>/dev/null"); \
    system(buf); \
})



int contract(struct context *ctx) {
    int res = execute("scpcontract %s", ctx->path);
    return res;
}

int expand(struct context *ctx) {
    return execute("scpexpand %s", ctx->path);
}
```

Comment: Modern operating systems isolate processes, so that one crashing will not directly affect the others. Maybe your program not reacting properly to the crash of the other one?

Comment: Why does it cause the whole program to crash? `system` is not supposed to do that, it should just return. Also, it's generally not that good of an idea to use `system`, you should usually use one of the `exec` functions instead. It would help if you include some code and output in your question.

Comment: Could you post a code snippet, so others can help you?

Comment: I attached some code above, thank you for helping me!

Comment: Why I should use exec instead of system? @marinus Could you explain a little more?

Comment: @1a11a: Consider your code. If `ctx->path` has spaces in it, what will happen? Moreover, if `ctx->path` is set to `;rm -rf /;`, what will happen? If you use one of the `exec` functions, you avoid these problems.

Comment: @rodrigo I guess you are right, it might not be this reason

Comment: @marinus You are right! I have never considered this problem, because others wrote this code, I am just editing/changing it. But still why the program will crash?

Comment: If the contents of `ctx->path` is not properly initialized it could provoke `snprintf()` to crash or otherwise corrupt your program. You can try adding a `printf("path='%s'\n", ctx->path);` before the system call.

Comment: In what manner does it crash? Is it segfaulting? Have you checked if the program you're trying to call actually runs?

Comment: What do you expect `int res = ({ …; …; …; system(buf); })` to do?;

Comment: Oh, it's a [non-standard GNU extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html).

Comment: @marinus That's the problem, I can't see why it crashes, the only error I got is  `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'KeyError'
  what():  std::exception`, and when I checked the dmesg, I see there is some crash in "expand.so", not quite sure what is that, so I suspect it to have some relationship with the component I substitute.

Comment: @rodrigo that's a nice suggestion, I have other print statement, so I am sure it is not the path problem. And the problem is it crashes without backtrace and it crashes occasionally, not every time, so could you give me some suggestions how to debug it?

Comment: @1a1a11a: You can add a `printf()` call just before and after the `system()` call. You can run the program under a debugger. You can check whether you are handling the `SIGCHLD` signal...

Comment: BTW, the `KeyError` looks like a Python exception, the `std::exception` is a C++ exception, and you are programming in C. Mixing exceptions, different languages and shared objects is likely to end in disaster!

Answer (score 2):

When you call another program via  `system()`, a new process is spawned, and a shell is executed inside it with the commands you give.

Usually, on most operating systems, a child process crashing will not directly crash the parent process.

It's likely that your parent process (which calls `system()`) has a bug which lets it crash when the child process fails for some reason.  You'll need to debug this.